# ¿Cómo ocultar el archivo WSDL de un servicio web?

Tags: c#, wsdl, .asmx

Necesito ocultar el wsdl de webservices ya que el área que certifica las aplicaciones en mi trabajo me lo esta pidiendo.

El detalle es que ya intenten utilizar:

```xml
<webServices>
  <protocols>
     <remove name="Documentation>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

y me marca el siguiente error lo cual me impide instanciar el webservices en el soap o en alguna otra aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También ya utilice

```xml
<webServices>
  <wsdlHelpGenerator href="Error.aspx"/>
</webServices>
```

pero esto no me oculta el archivo xml cuando le anexo `?wsdl` a la url.

**Estoy utilizando un .asmx y el framework 4.0 junto con VS2015**

Comment: La primera opción es la correcta (no te aparece el WSDL). Si el cliente no funciona porque necesita que el archivo está visible, lo que tienes que hacer es arreglar el cliente. Lo que es imposible es que el servidor adivine cuando tiene que mostrar el archivo y cuando no; o una cosa o la otra.

Comment: Podrías ser un poco más específico? ¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcione entonces mi WS en el cliente del Soap?

Comment: Con el remove Documentation el servicio sigue activo aunque no se vea la página, que es justo lo que quieres, me parece que como menciona SJuan76 tu problema está en el cliente que consume el WS, el cliente no debe utilizar el WSDL para consumir el web service, debes hacer un post directo al EndPoint

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo no usar web services asmx, podes ver de usar WCF ya que le podes agregar seguridad mas robusta.

De todas maneras, podes agregarle seguridad a tu web service soap  como se explica aquí: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4398/Authentication-for-Web-Services-using-SOAP-headers

Tambien podes probar en agregar un webform y escribir lo siguiente en tu webconfig:

```
<webServices>
  <wsdlHelpGenerator href="DenegarAcceso.aspx" />
</webServices>
```

Denegar acceso en el location donde se encuentra el asmx:

```
<system.web>
        <authorization>
              <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

Comment: ¡Hola agustín! 
Las dos cosas ya las tengo implementadas, según entiendo la autenticación por el headers es para controlar quién puede usar el web services, el detalle es que el área que certifica no quiere que se vea el xml que aparece cuando se le agrega "?wsdl" a la url.

Yo acostumbro a utilizar WCF pero este ya es un web services productivo implementado en varios sistemas, entonces realizar el cambio involucra mucha política de áreas de por medio.

Comment: Agregue codigo en la respuesta